# mysql conditional select query based on where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this query

```
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%') OR (column2 IS NOT NULL AND column2 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%')
```

that returns always `column1` value if a record of `Table1` satisfies where clause. But what I want is that the query returns `column1` value if the first part `LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%')` of where clause is satisfied, `column2` value if the second part `(column2 IS NOT NULL AND column2 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%')` is satisfied.
How should I modify the query to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN column1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%') THEN column1
       ELSE column2 
    END yourcolumn
FROM Table1
WHERE column1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%') 
    OR (column2 IS NOT NULL AND column2 LIKE CONCAT('%', :regex, '%')
```

Comment: Great, the query works like i wanted. But I have another question in relation to your answer: with your query the same comparison is performed twice, one on select and the other on the where cluse. Is possible optimize the query with only one of the two?